# How can I create an XPath that will look for button text or text from a nested element within the button?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am using Selenium web driver in order to test out a button and this button can either have text like so

```
<button>Foo</button>
```

Or it can look like this with nested tags of any type or depth.

```
<button><span>Foo</span></button>
```

I tried doing

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Foo']"));
```

But this would only get the text in the immediate tag level. I added a “//*” to the xpath and it would work for the nested element but then stop working for when the text is in the immediate level. I am looking for kind of OR condition or something where I can get this to work on both variations.

I am using Java and selenium web driver.

Thanks in Advance,

Juan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Foo')]"));
```

This will search for `button` element containing `Foo` text content in itself or any it child, exactly what you asking for.
BTW in Java we normally give objects names starting with non-capital letter, so it should be `driver`, not `Driver` there.